Updating an Entity Record not Found
I'm having a hard time understanding why my entity state not updating. The goal is to have the a client details updated. What I have done so far is have a form that populates the client data in inputs for change.
Once a field is changed and the user hits submit it should hit the HTTP post and process the change entity to the database, however, I get this error but I know that the record is present and the UpdateDetails page is populating the inputs with the correct data.
What I did notice is that when debugging the Client ID is passing 0 when it hits the HTTP post. Why is that happening? I have no idea.
I do have a working method for products and it is essentially doing the same process as the client but the product id is present. What am I overlooking here?
Technologies being used is ASP.NET Core 8 MVC.

DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

UpdateClient.cshtml:
<div class="row">
    <form asp-action="UpdateClient" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                <label asp-for="CompanyName">Company</label>
                <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" />
                <span class="help-block text-danger" asp-validation-for="CompanyName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                <label asp-for="BranchName">Branch Name</label>
                <input asp-for="BranchName" class="form-control" />
                <span class="help-block text-danger" asp-validation-for="BranchName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 mb-3">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span class="help-block text-danger" asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Address">Address</label>
            <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
            <span class="help-block text-danger" asp-validation-for="Address"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="ShippingAddress">Shipping Address</label>
            <input asp-for="ShippingAddress" class="form-control" />
            <span class="help-block text-danger" asp-validation-for="ShippingAddress"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

AdminController.cs:
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateClient(Client client)
{
    _clientRepository.UpdateClient(client);
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin");
}

ClientRepository.cs:
public void UpdateClient(Models.Client client)
{
    var result = _dbContext.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

When debugging this is what I mean that the client ID is showing an "id" of 0:


Make sure you need to supply ClientId, which mean that your form should consists of ClientId.

That did it I forgot, like you mentioned, to pass the ClientId in the form. I overlooked that. Rookie mistake thanks tho

Your real problem here is that you're using an EF Entity class (class Client) as an ASP.NET Form/ViewModel object - i.e. a DTO. But entity classes should not be used as DTOs for many reasons (especially for security reasons). LMK if you'd like to know more...

Sure I would like to know more on why that is @Dai

See my comments here, and my post here

Answering my own question. I forgot to pass the ClientId in the form so what I changed is from doing this

<div class="row">
    <form asp-action="UpdateClient" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">

        // Other fields

        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


to this

<div class="row">
    <form asp-action="UpdateClient" asp-controller="Admin" method="post">
        <input hidden asp-for="ClientId" /> <-- Needed for db detect which entity to change

        // Other fields

        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>



Two things you should adjust.
First, add ClientId as a hidden field within your form, and ensure the value exists when you do POST. As model binding will only bind the matched properties, so if there is no ClientId then the property will be defaulted. So, always have a hidden field that holds the primary key to that entry, and ensure to be bind to the model on POST.
Second, update this :
public void UpdateClient(Models.Client client)
{
    var result = _dbContext.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

to this :
public void UpdateClient(Models.Client client)
{
    _dbContext.Attach(client);
    var result = _dbContext.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

When you want to update an entry, you need to attach it first to the context, and then you can modify it so EF can track the changes on that entry.
